# Selecting href element within a DIV using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Within JQuery, to select all elements with a href attribute I would use:

```
$("[href]")
```

How would I select all elements with a href attribute within a specific DIV?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#myDiv [href]")
```

You need to identify the `div`, then use the [`descendant-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), which is just the space between the two.

This example used the [`id-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to identify a `div` with the ID `myDiv`.

This is functionally equivalent to using the [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```
$("#myDiv").find("[href]")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use second parameter - context:

```
$("[href]", '#yourDivID');
```

or `find()` method:

```
$('#yourDivID').find('[href]');
```